# Ubuntu System Tray in Python

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, tkinter

How do I put a program in the system tray (I don't think it's called like that in Linux) in python TKINTER for UBUNTU 9.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't believe you can do that using Tkinter. You will have to use the gtk libraries.

An example, found on a Ubuntu forum: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=bc369fc9343ae728577f1bdcd292caca&p=1053546&postcount=3

Here's an example (in Perl) of combining gtk and Tk. Gtk handles the tray icon, and the rest of the app uses Tk: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=626617

Comment: i used this same post for a project back in college!, super easy

Answer (score 7):

You have to use GTK. Do note that Ubuntu 10.04+ has a new, incompatible system tray. It's called AppIndicator; there's a python example here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators#Python%20version

Answer (score 3):

There is the [sytem tray protocol](http://standards.freedesktop.org/systemtray-spec/systemtray-spec-latest.html), which I believe both gnome and kde use.  You might be able to use it straight from python using ctype to call X11 methods.  But I would go with the GTK solution.